# Creating python script for HPQC: Setting filter properties

Tags: python

I have created a python script to connect to HPQC and get the bugs. I am trying to limit the amount of bugs I get by setting the Filter from the BugFactory. This is proving difficult to do, the documentation says that I need to set the properties like so

```
bugFactory = td.BugFactory

bugFilter = bugFactory.Filter

bugFilter.Filter("BG_STATUS") = "Open Or New Or In Progress Or Pending Retest"
```

when I do this I get this error from python:

```
bugFilter.Filter("BG_STATUS") = "Open Or New Or In Progress Or Pending Retest"
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

how can I set these properties?

Comment: Can you post a link to that documentation? I don't really understand your code but are you sure you shouldn't be instantiating those classes?

Comment: I don't know if the HPQC OTA_API_Reference.chm can be found online.

Answer (score 2):

The call would be

```
bugFilter.SetFilter('Field name', 'Setting')
```